# How can I dynamically add / remove servlets within a context?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, osgi, undertow

My environment is OSGi. I would like to run an embedded web server and add / remove servlets on-the-fly. In Jetty this seem to be possible for servlets contexts but not servlets within a context. It also seems to be possible with some extra work with Jetty.

Is this maybe possible with undertow or any other embedded web server?

Comment: It is possible to add-remove servlets dynamically with Jetty with some extra work.

Comment: It seems to be a little ugly in Jetty. That is why I ask about Undertow or alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusions: It does not really make sense within a context. The contexts already provide the possibility to handle some dynamic changes. Within a context endpoints should remain immutable. I wanted to share state (i.e. session information) across contexts, wich is not suggested by Jetty. However, there are several other options on implementation side to solve this. For example, include a servlets within the specific context or share state information in some other way.